# How to run Angular cli to https://localhost:4200 SSL mode

Tags: angular, ssl

I am trying to figure out how to configure my Angular CLI environment to run in SSL HTTPS mode.

Right now, it runs in the regular http://localhost:4200 but it can't access the webAPI which is running https mode. I was able to get data from the webapi via google postman but not with my angular app.

In my start, I typed mmc and found my personal cert which shows as

localhost   IIS Express Development

I read up on stackoverflow about changing the settings in a json file. I can't find the angular.json file. I found the package.json in the cli folder but when

how do I setup my angular app to run in https mode to access the data.

Right now, it just hangs.

Thanks.

Comment: go through this for more details https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run `ng serve --ssl true`